# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\integer does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have developed application in symfony2.3, it's working perfect in development environment but while I move to production it throws error. I tried but it can't resolve.

Following all error comes form different page : 
This error comes while I tried to access my home page.

> > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\integer does not exist' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php:795 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(795): ReflectionParameter->getClass() #1 [internal function]: Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->generateMethods(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(276): call_user_func(Array, Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php(155): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->generateProxyClass(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), '/opt/lampp/htdo...') #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php(71 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/UnexpectedValueException.php on line 51

When I clear cache of  production environment in command line, it throws following exception :

> > [Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\UnexpectedValueException]
> >       The type hint of parameter "user" in method "setUser" in class "Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\GroupEventComment" is invalid.
> >
> > [ReflectionException]
> >       Class Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\integer does not exist
> >
> > Once this has been solved then it throws to other class, so I can't understand that what's happen.

When I tried to login into page :

> > it shows me error like :
> >
> > Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__CollegelifeCommonBundleEntityUniversity.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 207

Comment: Check whether you have `icu` (both lib and php module) installed. I have seen various cases with "integer"-ish problem when this lib/module was not installed.

Comment: Thanks jovan, but how should I verify? and it's very strange that development environment does not throw single error of this kind.

Comment: What Linux OS distro/version are you running your `prod` on?

Comment: Also, can you update the question with your entity code where this "integer" problem occurs?

Comment: Jovan Ubntu 12 with symfony2.3

Comment: Please explain your answer so it helps to resolve issue

Comment: Can be a mispelling of the integer class (upper/lower case)? Your dev environment is based on a case insensitive file system?

Comment: I have updated my question with error occurs while I clear cache in production environment.

Comment: Jovan / Matteo , there is icu module has been updated, so it doesn't matter, but some page I am accessing perfectly but while access some page like login it throws me an error as I described in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and resolved it.
Because My Entity's setting.

You can't type hint on a scalar type (integer/string/boolean etc) in PHP. e.g.

```
public function setSortOrder(\integer $sortOrder)
```

Should be:

```
public function setSortOrder($sortOrder)
```

Comment: For completeness' sake: as of php > 7 it IS possible to scalar types as typehint